# COUNTIF if values are not in one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel**

```
         A       B       C        D        E        F
1        4                       400
2                                          0
3                                                  700
4                                  0         
5                                300
6                                                    0
7                                                    0
8                                        100
9
```

---

In the above `Excel` table I have values in different cells. 
In cell `A1` I want to count the number of cells that contain a value `<> 0`. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this formula:

```
A1 = COUNTIF((D1,E2,F3,D4,D5,F6,F7,E8),0)
```

However, with this formula I get `#VALUE!`. 
I assume the issue is that the `array` for the `COUNTIF` formula is not in one row.

One way of solving the issue would be to make a helper column in which I put all the values in one row but I am wondering if there is another way of doing it without any helper column?

Comment: Do you want to count these cells seperately or can you use the range `D1:F8`?

Comment: It needs to seperately.

Comment: If it were me, I'd have a table of the same size as a "mask", with 1's for the cells I was interested in, and 0's otherwise. eg, if the area I am interested in is B1:F9, I have another table (say H1:L9) containing 1's where I care about the corresponding cell in B1:F9, and 0's where I don't. The formula =SUMPRODUCT(H1:L9,INT((B1:F9<>0))) should return the count of the cells of interest which have a value <> 0. The mask makes adding new cells of interest straightforward. I realize the OP didnt want a "helper column", but this method may be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a non-continuous range is a must you could use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"D1","E2","F3","D4:D5","F6:F7","E8"}),"<>0"))
```

Note that this is volatile!

Comment: Personally, I am not a fan of INDIRECT(). If the OP adds a row in their spreadsheet above the table, then this function will go wrong, as Excel won't change the string "D1" to "D2"

Comment: @DS_London, ohhh don't get me wrong. I ***never*** use this personally!

Comment: Phew! You had me worried. IMHO my answer below avoids this ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to your regional settings.
By default, Excel uses the list separator defined under regional settings in Control Panel. The US English version of Excel uses a comma (,) for list separator by default, while other international versions may use a semicolon (;). Try to put a semicolon between range and condition.

```
A1 = COUNTIF(D1,E2,F3,D4,D5,F6,F7,E8; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more typing but if you are intent on using specific cells:

```
=SUM(D1<>0,E2<>0,F3<>0,D4<>0,D5<>0,F6<>0,F7<>0,E8<>0)
```

The D1<>0 test will return TRUE or FALSE. In the SUM() function, Excel treats TRUE as 1, and FALSE as 0. And you don't have to use INDIRECT() which can store up trouble for the future.