# COUNTIF with interruptions within the array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |      A                     B        C       D         E    |    F     |    G      H       I
---|------------------------------------------------------------|----------|------------------------
1  |                            Q1       Q2      Q3       Q4    |  Total   |    Q1     Q2      Q3
---|------------------------------------------------------------|----------|------------------------
2  |  Revenue_Product_A        500      300    200      100     |   1.100  |   900      0       0
3  |                                                            |          |
4  |  Rolling-Count                                             |          |     3      2       1
5  |                                                            |          |
6  |
7
```

In the above table I have the quarter timeline of the revenues of a certain product.

As you can see in `Column F` there is the total of all quarters.

In `Row 4` I want to count the **last 3 quarters** on a **rolling basis** in case the revenue in is `<>0`.

Therefore, I used this formula from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204550/countif-if-values-are-not-in-one-row):

```
G4 =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"G2";"E2";"D2"});"<>0"))
```

It works but the issue is that it can happened that the user needs to insert rows and columns but the cell reference in this formula is fixed. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a solution in which I can **directly refer** to the cells?

Comment: Try to replace the `2` part with a formula that returns that number. Maybe something like counting total rows of column F, so if users enter new rows, the count will be updated, and then your formula will refer to `G2,G3,G4,G5...` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`/`CHOOSE`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1;2;3};G2;E2;D2)<>0))
```

[image]